# Rewriting the connection database - Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Someone I can explain how I can rewrite the connection database to another existing database and uses it as the default.

The database of exchanging happens after performing a call to a webservice.

This is possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

As [official docs](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html) says, all you need to do is to set up all your databases in `app/config/config.yml` file. Here's a little example:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: customer
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     "%default_database_host%"
                port:     "%default_database_port%"
                dbname:   "%default_database_name%"
                user:     "%default_database_user%"
                password: "%default_database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
            customer:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     "%customer_database_host%"
                port:     "%customer_database_port%"
                dbname:   "%customer_database_name%"
                user:     "%customer_database_user%"
                password: "%customer_database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: customer
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    AppBundle: ~
            customer:
                connection: customer
                mappings:
                    CustomerBundle: ~
```

Follow along with the examples in the article to learn how to perform queries against any of the connections.